# Hide application name overlapping 'Burger' image on support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

I am trying support.v7.widget.Toolbar. Want to show my app name on right of burger image.
I tried following code.

```
    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    // Set the custom toolbar
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    drawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            drawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            toolbar,  /* toolbar */
            R.string.empty,  /* "open drawer" description */
            R.string.empty  /* "close drawer" description */
    ) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

But it overlaps app name with burger image. Also, I have tried toolbar.setTitle("null") and setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false). Still it shows app name which overlaps with burger image.

Also, my custom toolbar layout is empty. And if I user toolbar.setTitle("App Name"), still it shows 2 app names. 1 with my desired effect and 2nd with overlapping name with image.

[image: after setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);]

After removing setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

[image]
 Please help. Thanks in advance.

Here,is my code from styles.xml

```
    <!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarker</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<color name="primary">#457C50</color>
<color name="primaryDarker">#580C0C</color>
```

And here is my code from manifest

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!-- Splash screen -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.mayu.viratkohli.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Home screen -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.mayu.viratkohli.activities.HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is my updated layout for activity

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MyActivity" >

<!-- The main content view -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />
</LinearLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="#457C50" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left Drawer" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you try changing this `R.string.empty` to something other than an empty string in your drawer toggle

Comment: @tyczj yes I tried, but didn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question updated with corrected layout for my activity holding toolbar layout. Use LinearLayout instead of FrameLayout as parent view of your toolbar layout which will result in hiding ur overlapping application name. And dont use getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false) which will prevent hiding of application name from toolbar. Thanks a lot for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't disabled the decor provided ActionBar. Your theme needs to inherit from Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar or Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar if you are using the Toolbar. See the style snippet below

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    ...
</style>
```

or

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may remove the third argument "toolbar" in the ActionBarDrawerToggle construction. Besides setting a title of the toolbar.

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this,           /* host Activity */
        drawerLayout,   /* DrawerLayout object */
        R.string.empty, /* "open drawer" description */
        R.string.empty  /* "close drawer" description */
) {

    /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
};

toolbar.setTitle("App Name");
```

In addition to above, you'd better to use the NoActionBar theme:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>
</resources>
```

And the layout/activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        (...)

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you use a LinearLayout as parent ViewGroup? Don't you use a FrameLayout? Please show your layout xml.

Comment: Wow! It worked when I changed parent view of toolbar layout to LinearLayout from FrameLayout. Now, I cant see overlapping application name. And can see app name at proper place by removing setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);